# LINQ order by syntax

Tags: .net, linq

The following line will not compile because of the order by clause. What am I doing wrong with the syntax?

```
   ddlMIP.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("MIP_NO").ToString()).Distinct().OrderBy(row => row.Field<string>("MIP_NO").ToString()).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select is projecting a collection of strings since you are calling ToString()

that means that in your OrderBy the value of "row" in the llambda is actually going to be a string itself.  You could probably just do OrderBy(r => r)

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlMIP.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("MIP_NO").ToString()).Distinct().OrderBy(row => row.Field("MIP_NO").ToString()).ToList();
```

It looks like the list operator in the OrderBy() section is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where you're going wrong; when it comes to the ordering, you're only left with a collection of the strings that were previously selected in the `.Select` method. What you're trying to do can easily be achieved with a minor alteration. The following will select the field `MIP_NO` as a string, and then assign it to a distinct ordered enumerable collection.

```
ddlMIP.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("MIP_NO").ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(mipNo => mipNo);
```